# How to defeat browser dialog popup when calling Wicket setResponsePage() from modal window?

Tags: java, browser, wicket, modal-dialog

How to defeat IE and Firefox dialog popup when trying to setResponsePage() from a wicket modalWindow per below.  Dialog popup demands an answer to:  "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved."

```
    AjaxLink signInContainer = new AjaxLink("signInContainer") {
        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            target.appendJavascript("Wicket.Window.unloadConfirmation = false;");

            modalWindow.close(target);
            setResponsePage(SignInPage.class);
            modalWindow.close(target);
        }
    };
```

-Rich

Answer (score 10):

In wicket 6.x and above you can simply set `showUnloadConfirmation` to `false`:

```
final ModalWindow modalWindow = new ModalWindow("modalWindow");
modalWindow.showUnloadConfirmation(false);
```

Answer (score 9):

`target.appendJavascript("Wicket.Window.unloadConfirmation = false;");` doesn't work because it must run before `modal.show(target);`.

You could either prepend, instead of append, the script, when opening the window:

```
add(new AjaxLink<Void>("show") {
    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        target.prependJavascript("Wicket.Window.unloadConfirmation = false;");
        modal.show(target);
    }
});
```

or add a behavior, to execute it on `onload`:

```
modal.add(new AbstractBehavior() {
    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        response.renderOnLoadJavascript("Wicket.Window.unloadConfirmation = false;");
    }
});
```

But, it must be called *before opening* the modal window, not when navigating away from the page (`setResponsePage()`).

Comment: To use the latter approach in Wicket 6, `Behavior` should be used instead of `AbstractBheavior`, and since `renderOnLoadJavaScript` doesn't exist anymore, one would use `response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forScript("...", id));`.

Comment: `OnDomReadyHeaderItem`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** *This is a hack, use the alternative described in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8679946/176897).*

Try this:

```
public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    modal.close(target);
    CharSequence url = urlFor(HomePage.class, new PageParameters("gone=true"));
    target.appendJavascript("window.location='" + url + "';");
}
```

Comment: Would this bypass Wicket's built-in PageMap?  Would there be any negative side effects?

Comment: This would be the same as opening a bookmarkable page from a static link or browser bookmark. I can't see how it could cause any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `setResponsePage()` should be accompanied by some other methods to behave properly.  For example, I often include `setRedirect(true)` when using this technique.  I'm not sure what all is going on behind the scenes there, but perhaps try that.