# Wicket: Catch JavaScript event of confirm dialog when user press'es "cancel"

Tags: javascript, ajax, wicket

We have an AjaxButton like:

```
add(new AjaxButton("ajax-cancel-button", form) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 839803820502260006L;

    @Override
    protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
        super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);
        attributes.getAjaxCallListeners().add(new ConfirmCallListener(833L));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
        // repaint the feedback panel so that it is hidden
        target.add(feedback);

        // DO ACTION
    }
});
```

ConfirmCallListener looks like that:

```
public class ConfirmCallListener extends AjaxCallListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7355235720213137963L;

    public ConfirmCallListener(long id) {
        onPrecondition("if (!confirm('Do you want this')) {" 
                + js + "; return false;}");
    }
}
```

What I want now is to catch the JavaScript event when the user presses "Cancel" in the Confirm dialog (NOT Ok). I can catch the event when the user presses "OK". But I want to react also on "cancel" events (cause some Loading bar should disapear when the user presses cancel).

How can I catch the cancel event of the confirm box?

Thanks!
Sebastian

Comment: Are you using ModalWindow? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013364/how-to-defeat-browser-dialog-popup-when-calling-wicket-setresponsepage-from-mo/8679946#8679946

Comment: No, but thanks for the hint I guess this is already a possible solution.